# embed my special font in an html web page

Tags: html, embedded-fonts

I already found many answers on how to embed a font in a web page but I am asking what is the most recent and efficient one to use as some methods are very old and does not display correctly

please advise I have a commercial font I want to embed inside my web page and to be displayed in all new major browsers (we can ignore IE 6)

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ and you are set.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Just download a kit or generate your own, open the sample page included in the kit and see how it's done.

Comment: fontsquirrel is much nicer then other solutions, provided your font allows this sort of rendering.